# Why does a joint leakage MPC protocol not directly apply to a disjoint leakage requirement?

Tags: multiparty-computation

In the paper "[Multiparty Computation Secure Against Continual Memory Leakage](http://web.mit.edu/eboyle/www/LR-MPC-STOC12.pdf)" on pg. 1239 the footnote at the bottom points out the difference between $joint$ leakage and $disjoint$ leakage.  The authors say the weakly leakage resilient protocol of BGG+11 cannot be directly used because it only applies to $joint$ leakage.

My understanding is the adversary has been made more powerful and is able to perform disjoint leakage (i.e. he can make leakage requests on random modules at any time).

I was wondering if somebody could explain this footnote a bit more clearly.  Why does a weakly resilient protocol not apply directly?